# How to remove or hide mat-option after selection in mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table, mat-select

I have this table using `mat-table` and I'm adding a dynamic row on it by clicking a button. One of the column of the said table has a drop down using `mat-select` with a static `mat-option`. Please visit this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-zvczsa?file=app/app.component.html) for my sample reproduction of my table.

My primary goal is to hide the item that I already selected previously.

[image]

Hope you can guide me on how to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method to get the filtered services in your component something like

```
getServices(selectedService){
   let selecteServices:any[]=this.form.value?.servicesArr?.map(s=> s.services)||[];
   return this.services.filter(s=> s == selectedService || selecteServices.every(sv=> sv != s))
}
```

Then use this method to fetch filtered services from UI

```
 <mat-select #ser formControlName="services" (selectionChange)="onSeviceChange($event, element)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let service of getServices(ser.value)" [value]="service">
                {{ service }}
              </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-ceacl5?file=app/app.component.html)